# How to map null values with AutoMapper for an specific mapping?

Tags: c#, .net, mapping, automapper

I found this solution [AutoMapper - setting destination string to null actually makes it string.Empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1526813/automapper-setting-destination-string-to-null-actually-makes-it-string-empty)

but It uses the Initialize method so all the mappings behavior would change along the app : O

And I just need do it for a specific mapping.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Found a solution:

```
Mapper.Initialize( Conf =>
  {
    Conf.ForSourceType<MyGreatViewModel>().AllowNullDestinationValues = true;
  } );
```

Thanks guys : )

Take care of your destination field types (remember you need nullable types. e.g. 'Byte?' )